# Unable to delete _id field from object after create using feathersjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, mongoose, feathersjs

i want to modify my hook.data object in my node application after insertion of data. actually i'm not able to.

```
create: [function(hook, next) {
      delete hook.data._id;
      hook.data = { problem: hook.data }
      postJson(hook.app.get('jsprintUrl'), hook.data)
        .then(data =>{
          hook.result = data;
          next()
        })
    }]
```

**result:** still _id is exist

```
{
"_id": "59ca334e7bc4e06b140aadf9",
    "algorithm": [
        {
            "name": "SA"
        }
    ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i update object using the hook.result in following way and hook.result will have its Mongoose documents converted to plain objects. more information [reference link](https://legacy.docs.feathersjs.com/databases/mongoose.html#modifying-results-with-the-toobject-hook)

```
create: [function(hook, next) {
      delete hook.result._id;
      hook.result = { problem: hook.result }
      postJson(hook.app.get('jsprintUrl'), hook.result)
        .then(data =>{
          hook.result = data;
          next()
        })
    }]
```

**result:** It was removed from response

```
{
  "algorithm": [
        {
            "name": "SA"
        }
    ]
}
```